# Expand search view action bar and put text into it

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I have implemented searchview in actionbar and it is working fine. In viewpager if user switch between fragment I want to keep the state of searchview, to do so whenever fragment switch I applied query and show search result in recycler until now it is working like charm except I want to expand my searchview and put a query into it on fragment change method. I have seen lots of thread on it and I have applied multiple solutions none worked.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

In onCreateOptionsMenu i am inflating my menu.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
    this.menu = menu;
    searchActionBar(menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

In search Actionbar i am fetching query result and save query text to mQuery and clear this text when searchview collapse.

```
private void searchActionBar(Menu menu){

    searchViewItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    searchViewAndroidActionBar = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchViewItem);

    searchViewAndroidActionBar.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    searchViewAndroidActionBar.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            searchViewAndroidActionBar.clearFocus();
            mQuery = query;
            fetchSearchResult(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
          return true;
        }
    });

    MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchViewItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            mQuery="";
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

This function is called when fragment switch in viewpager , if there is any query I want to set in searchview. But searchview doesn't expand. Although query submit function is running.

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isResumed() && isVisibleToUser) {
        if (searchViewAndroidActionBar != null) {
            searchViewAndroidActionBar.setFocusable(true);
            searchViewAndroidActionBar.setQuery(mQuery,true);           
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.